# My htaccess rewrite doesnt work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a folder structure like this

```
/localhost/parent/
```

I have an .htaccess residing in

```
/localhost/parent/
```

I want to rewrite everything from `/localhost/parent/WebContent/` to `/localhost/parent/`

here is my code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ WebContent/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^WebContent/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ WebContent/$1
```

For some reason the first two lines work fine, but the rest doesn't work. So I am able to redirect only homepage.

### Update

```
RewriteBase /parent/

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ WebContent/$1

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !WebContent
RewriteRule (.*) /parent/WebContent/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Goes into an infinite loop. I just need to avoid that loop now

Comment: I'm not really good at apache rewrite rules, but this is my rule for "friendly url" : RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301] Maybe it will be useful for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /parent/WebContent/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !WebContent
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /parent/WebContent/$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try switching the order of the lines so that

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

comes before everything else.

You could also try adding this line:

```
RewriteBase /WebContent/
```